# Can I call a phtml file as a block?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, page

I have a file in my package `myPackage/default/template/testpage/test.phtml` with something like:

```
<?php
echo 'Test'
?>
```

How can I call it as a block in a `cms->page`?

I tried to use `{{block type="page/template_testpage_test" template="testpage/test.phtml"}}` but nothing happens.
How should I call the `type=A/B`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic block for templates is `core/template`. So the CMS code in your case is

```
{{block type="core/template" template="testpage/test.phtml"}}
```

But in order for this to work, you have to add the block type `core/template` to the whitelist in *System > Permissions > Blocks*